# RStudio does not see some directories on server cluster

Tags: r, rstudio, cluster-computing, rstudio-server

Working in RStudio on a cluster, files and directories in my home directory (which is the working directory) are visible and accessible, but another directory (a project directory, larger storage, to which I do have read/write access) is not visible in the navigation pane, and cannot be set as a working directory.

I made a symbolic link to this directory in my home folder, but RStudio does not see this folder either.

Home directory space is limited, so I cannot simply bring my datafiles into it. Any suggestions?

EDIT: The problem has been remedied. Unfortunately the info is not particularly enlightening. Our cluster IT folks chatted with RStudio devs, and were told that RStudio server doesn't follow symbolic linked directories, and this was a design decision.  R -vs- RStudio -vs- RStudio Server (web interface) all behave slightly differently even though the later two products have a similar code base at the core.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a proper way to do this, but as a workaround you can use in the R console:

```
setwd("<directory>")
```

Followed by either clicking on the small arrow next to the folder name in the `Console` pane

[image]

or use `More -> Go To Working directory` in the `Files` pane.

Comment: I appreciate the response.

The issue is that I have a directory, which I know exists, and I can navigate to in browser or command line, but which R does not recognize, so I cannot set it as the working directory.

I am trying to chase down why R would not see a directory. I've tried it in RStudio and R from the cmd line.

Comment: @PhilGordon Interesting. Do you get any error message when using `setwd` with this directory?

Comment: yes, the error is:
Error in file(file, “rt”) : cannot open the connection

In addition:  Warning message:

In file(file, “rt”) :

                Cannot open file ‘/cluster/folder/2799_Simple.csv’: Nosuch file or directory

this comes from trying to open the file, and likewise trying to setwd to the folder says no directory exists.

Comment: @PhilGordon Ok. I see from your edit that it is expected behaviour that links don‘t work. Does my trick work when you use the actual directory instead of the link?

Comment: It did not originally, though our IT folks at the cluster must have changed something about the directories (they for some reason do not feel inclined to tell me what) that allows Rstudio to view the folders now, and setwd works in the console. Thanks again for the responses and interest! I apologize that i can't give a more satisfactory explanation.